# gorm m2m custom connection table, foreign key constraint setting is invalid

Tags: go, go-gorm

I try to migrate mysql's sql to gorm

sql:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
    `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `group` (
    `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin_group` (
    `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `admin_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `group_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `create_at` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `update_at` DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `admin_id` (`admin_id`),
    KEY `group_id` (`group_id`),
    UNIQUE (`admin_id`, `group_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`admin_id`) REFERENCES `admin`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `group`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

gorm:

```golang
type Admin struct {
    ID     uint64
    Groups *[]Group `gorm:"many2many:AdminGroup;foreignKey:id;joinForeignKey:admin_id;References:id;joinReferences:group_id;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
}

type Group struct {
    ID   uint64
    Name string
}

type AdminGroup struct {
    ID       uint64
    AdminID  uint64     `gorm:"index:,unique,composite:admgro;not null;"`
    GroupID  uint64     `gorm:"index:,unique,composite:admgro;not null;"`
    CreateAt *time.Time `gorm:"autoCreateTime;"`
    UpdateAt *time.Time `gorm:"autoCreateTime;"`
}

    err = db.AutoMigrate(&Admin{}, &Group{}, &AdminGroup{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = db.SetupJoinTable(&Admin{}, "Groups", &AdminGroup{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

**But the `admin_group` table created by gorm has no foreign key constraints**

gorm ddl:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `admin_group` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `admin_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `group_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `create_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_admin_group_admgro` (`admin_id`,`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

I hope to get the same ddl as mysql sql

sql ddl:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `admin_group` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `admin_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `group_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `create_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `update_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `admin_id_2` (`admin_id`,`group_id`),
  KEY `admin_id` (`admin_id`),
  KEY `group_id` (`group_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `admin_group_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`admin_id`) REFERENCES `admin` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `admin_group_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `group` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

How do I need to modify my gorm model to correctly generate foreign key constraints?

---

```
gorm.io/driver/mysql v1.5.1 
gorm.io/gorm v1.25.4 
github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql v1.7.1 
go version go1.21.0 linux/amd64 
mysql:8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with your mentioned structs.By making two changes

1. Changing Admin{},Group{},AdminGroup{} struct's ID as "primaryKey"
2. Calling AutoMigrate() for every struct separately

code:-

```
type Admin struct {
    ID     uint64   `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Groups *[]Group `gorm:"many2many:AdminGroup;foreignKey:id;joinForeignKey:admin_id;References:ID;joinReferences:group_id;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
}

type Group struct {
    ID   uint64 `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name string
}

type AdminGroup struct {
    ID       uint64     `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    AdminID  uint64     `gorm:"index:,unique,composite:admgro;not null"`
    GroupID  uint64     `gorm:"index:,unique,composite:admgro;not null"`
    CreateAt *time.Time `gorm:"autoCreateTime;"`
    UpdateAt *time.Time `gorm:"autoCreateTime;"`
}
     err := DB.AutoMigrate(&AdminGroup{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = DB.AutoMigrate(&Group{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = DB.AutoMigrate(&Admin{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = DB.SetupJoinTable(&Admin{}, "Groups", &AdminGroup{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

GORM DLL:-

```
CREATE TABLE `admin_group` (
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `admin_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `group_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `create_at` DATETIME(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_at` DATETIME(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_admin_group_admgro` (`admin_id`,`group_id`),
  KEY `fk_admin_group_group` (`group_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_admin_group_admin` FOREIGN KEY (`admin_id`) REFERENCES `admin` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_admin_group_group` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `group` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: It seems that the AdminGroup table needs to be created in advance

Comment: according to your requirement (yes, it needs to be created prior to other two table) moreover, there may be any other solution for that you need to change the struct "AdminGroup" and "Group"

Answer (score 1):

If the [GORM auto migration](https://gorm.io/docs/migration.html) is not enough (I.e. does not create these foreign key constraints as expected),  you might need to define the foreign keys and constraints manually.
That would mean creating a function to manually handle the migration with the specific foreign key constraints, indexes, and unique constraints as you mentioned.

```golang
package main

import (
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "time"
)

type Admin struct {
    ID     uint64
    Groups []Group `gorm:"many2many:admin_group;"`
}

type Group struct {
    ID   uint64
    Name string
}

type AdminGroup struct {
    ID       uint64
    AdminID  uint64 `gorm:"index:,unique,composite:admgro;not null;"`
    GroupID  uint64 `gorm:"index:,unique,composite:admgro;not null;"`
    CreateAt time.Time `gorm:"autoCreateTime;"`
    UpdateAt time.Time `gorm:"autoCreateTime;"`
}

func main() {
    dsn := "user:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/dbname?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local"
    db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }

    err = db.AutoMigrate(&Admin{}, &Group{}, &AdminGroup{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Manual migration for foreign key constraints
    err = db.Transaction(func(tx *gorm.DB) error {
        err = tx.Exec(`
            ALTER TABLE admin_group
            ADD CONSTRAINT admin_group_ibfk_1
            FOREIGN KEY (admin_id) REFERENCES admin (id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
            ADD CONSTRAINT admin_group_ibfk_2
            FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES group (id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
        `).Error
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

The manual migration is performed inside a transaction after the `AutoMigrate` method is called, with:

- an `ALTER TABLE` statement is used to manually add the foreign key constraints to the `admin_group` table.
- `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE` options are specified as requested.

That should explicitly set the foreign key constraints to match the desired DDL.

Answer (score 0):

One better option is to use the SQL script and migration using golang-migrate. I can assist you with setting up golang migrate and running the script, if required